# Is there a FreeRTOS library for an Arduino Nano 33 BLE?

Tags: arduino-ide, library, arduino-nano-ble

I can't seem to find any library online so I can start developing FreeRTOS tasks for the Arduino Nano 33 BLE in the Arduino IDE. Is FreeRTOS incompatible with this Arduino?

Comment: the Arduino mbed platform for the Nano BLE is based on mbed RTOS. why do you want to use FreeRTOS?

Comment: I have a college assignment where I need to install and characterize FreeRTOS on 3 different systems, the ones I chose with the help of the professor were the Arduino Uno, the ESP-32 and the Arduino Nano 33. Since I never used ESP-32 and Arduino Nano 33 I just assumed the professor knew it would work, but it really seems like it doesn't support FreeRTOS. I don't know how to use mbed RTOS and I don't have a lot of time to work on this project, so it wouldn't make sense to use anything besides FreeRTOS, which is the only RTOS I can use.

Comment: esp32 arduino platform is RTOS too

Comment: Forget about the Arduino Uno. It's CPU is much to weak to run any OS.

Comment: The Arduino Uno actually runs FreeRTOS pretty well and is easily programmable because there is a library for it inside the Arduino IDE.